# Can't find the "Override requests with workspace project" in Chrome DevTools Canary

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

For the life of me I can't find where to enable this setting: **Override requests with workspace project** in Chrome Canary v64.0.3

Where do you enable this feature?

I learned about this feature from here: https://umaar.com/dev-tips/162-network-overrides/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's behind an experiment (https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/ui#experiments) then it'll be under experiments in the settings panel of devtools.

Please do be warned though, this is an experimental feature, there are bugs and it might not work as intended.

We are trying hard to get it fully released soon (on Canary) but it needs to be a 1st class feature before we will feel ready to release it.

Answer (score 11):

Currently with 65 Chrome Canary it's not experimental anymore.

**But you still cannot "Save for overrides" XHR requests.**

This restriction is only in UI. To get XHR request override:

1. Open *"Sources tab"* in Chrome Canary DevTools and *"Overrides"* sub-tab under it.
2. Check *"Enable Local Overrides"* and add a folder to store changes in the filesystem.
3. Open *"Network"* tab in Chrome Canary DevTools and select XHR request
4. Press *"Open in new tab"*
5. Go to new opened tab Chrome DevTools - *"Network"*
6. Select the first request in the list and *"Save for Overrides"* button appears.

---

You can follow the gif from question starting step 5:

[image: gif from question]

Answer (score 1):

This feature is now enabled in chrome stable you can follow these step:

In chrome go to "Sources tab" then in devtools "Overrides" click "Enable Local Overrides" then create a folder to put the changes in the filesystem. Go to 
"Network" then select XHR request then "Open in new tab" then  go to new opened tab Chrome DevTools - "Network"
pick the first request in the list and normally you will have a "Save for Overrides" button appears.

Answer (score 0):

I think they might have shipped the feature, so it's no longer behind an experiment.

Try the workflow that Umaar outlined, omitting the step about enabling the experiment.

Haven't tried it myself yet, so I could be wrong

Comment: I tried a lot to get this to work, but no success. I was able to map the folder as detailed here https://developers.google.com/web/tools/setup/setup-workflow but mapping the local file the select dialog just disappears and the networks style.css is always served

Answer (score 0):

The feature is no longer an experiment in Chrome Canary (current version at the time of this: 64.0.3261.0). You can start to use it now. It will take a little time to arrive in Chrome stable.

[image: Network override]

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version of Chrome Canary (Version `65.0.3317.2`) you still need to enable dev tool experiments. The option is still behind the experiment flag @kayce-basques . I also followed the tutorial of Umaar - also using GitHub for testing - but I don't get any visible website changes after pressing F5.

Has someone figured out how to get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

(1) Select the Overrides Tab in the Sources Panel.

(2) Click the Setup Overrides ( + icon) to add an empty folder.

(3) Confirm that Enable Network Overrides are enabled.

(4) Select the js file to be persisted on the Network Tab and display the source code in the code editor.

(5) Add code “console.log (‘hello world’);” to the beginning of the source code.

(6) Right click on the source code, select command [Save for overrides] on the context menu.

(7) Reload the current page after saving the file.

(8) Open the Console Panel and check the result.